# Storing Values from One Array into Another Larger Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a range of signals of different frequencies. I am finding it difficult to store amplitude vs time into another storage matrix for each frequency ranging from 0 to 50 Hz. Example, for a frequency of 20 Hz, I want to store the amplitude vs time for that frequency, then for 21 Hz I want to store the amplitude vs time for that frequency etc, until I have all of them in a large matrix. I am getting so confused at this point with indexing and syntax, any help welcome!

```
import numpy as np 
  
max_freq = 50
s_frequency = np.arange(0,51,0.1)
fs = 200
time = np.arange(0,5-(1/fs),(1/fs))
x = np.empty((len(time)), dtype=np.float32)
i = 0
j = 0 
full_array = np.empty((len(s_frequency),len(time),len(time)), dtype=np.float32)
amplitude = np.zeros(999)

for f1 in s_frequency:  
    i = 0
    for t in time:
        amplitude[i] = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
        i = i + 1
         
    full_array[i] = ([time], [amplitude])
```

I have also tried the following:

```
import numpy as np 

max_freq = 50
s_frequency = np.arange(0,50.1,0.1)
fs = 200
time = np.arange(0,5-(1-fs),(1/fs))


#full_array = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.outer(s_frequency,time))

full_array = np.empty((len(s_frequency),len(time), len(time)), dtype=np.float32)

for f1 in s_frequency:
    
    array = []
    
    for i, t in enumerate(time):
        
      amplitude = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
      array.insert(i,amplitude)
      
full_array[i] = [time, array]
```

Comment: Its not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would like an array that will hold for each frequency i.e. 20 Hz the amplitude vs time for that signal.  I hope that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like you're trying to initialize a 2-dimensional grid (i.e. a matrix) where you have a dimension for time and one for frequency. Here is what I would do:

```py
import numpy as np

max_freq = 50
s_frequency = np.arange(0,51,0.1)
fs = 200
time = np.arange(0,5-(1/fs),(1/fs))

full_array = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.outer(s_frequency,time))
```

No explicit for-loops or index handling needed. [`np.outer()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) will give you a 2D grid (i.e. a matrix) of frequency versus time. Now whats left is to compute the sine of 2 Pi times that grid value. Very conveniently `numpy` functions do accept arrays as input, thus we can simply call `np.sin(2*np.pi*np.outer(s_frequency,time)`.

Not sure what `x` and `j` are good for in your code and why `full_array` should be 3-diemsional. Would you like to include a spatial component as well?

By the way, a construct like this:

```
i = 0
for t in time:
    amplitude[i] = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
    i = i + 1
```

can easily be avoided in python, thanks to pythons build-in [`enumerate()`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) function. It would then look like this:

```
for i, t in enumerate(time):
    amplitude[i] = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
```

which does essentially the same, but you don't have to explicitly create the index `i = 0` and manually incerement it in every iteration `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Better yet `amplitude = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*time)`

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post again to try and be more clear. I am trying to create a storage matrix that will hold for each frequency, a signal of amplitude vs time. Thank you for the time at the end for the enumerate() function, I'll be implementing that from now on. @Tinu